# Looping through form values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops, post

I have a form with 8 fields. I have created this form with a for loop like this:

```
    echo '<form name="num" method="post">';//create a form that uses the POST method for submission
    for($i=0; $i<8; $i++){//loop 8 times, and display 8 input fields
         echo '<input id='.$i.' type="number" name="num[]" >';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" class="submit" name="num-submit" value="Go">
          </form>';
```

I want to loop thorugh all these fields, get the numbers that the user has submitted, and do some arithmetic with the values.

I have looked at other questions similar to mine, in stack overflow; I've tried out this response by Marc B:

"

> Given:

```
<input type="text" name="foo[]" /> 
<input type="text" name="foo[]" />
```

> etc... in your form, you'd loop over them with

```
foreach($_POST['foo'] as $index => $value) {
... }
```

"

I have applied that response to my own code:

```
    if (!empty($_POST['num-submit'])) {//If the form is submitted, execute the following code

        foreach($_POST['num'] as $name => $value) {// Loop over each item in the form.
             //code to add elements (the numbers submitted) together
        }
    }
```

This completely works for me but I just don't understand why this is the solution. I would like a full explanation for why this is the solution and why the name of the input fields have to be `foo[]` or `num[]` with the square brackets (doesn't that just create an array?). Also, it would be great if you could also help to to add the numbers together in that loop.
Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the solutions but you can easily write

```
<input type="text" name="foo[0]" /> 
<input type="text" name="foo[1]" />
```

or via key names

```
<input type="text" name="foo[keyname]" />
<input type="text" name="foo[keyothername]" />
```

Why it works?
I think you will find your answer at links below

- http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php

Important parts are:

> Specifying array keys is optional in HTML. If you do not specify the keys, the array gets filled in the order the elements appear in the form. Our first example will contain keys 0, 1, 2 and 3.
>
> PHP also understands arrays in the context of form variables. You may, for example, group related variables together, or use this feature to retrieve values from a multiple select input. For example, let's post a form to itself and upon submission display the data.

So in simplier words when you name form variable and it looks like array name PHP underestands it and translates into array in your script.

To sum values use [array_sum()](http://php.net/array_sum) built in function:

```
if (!empty($_POST['foo'] && is_array($_POST['foo'])) {
    echo array_sum($_POST['foo']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it creates the array.
You are looping to find sum the array.There is a function which used to calculate the sum of array
You can use

```
$sum = array_sum($num);
```

It this do not work then you can use the below one.The above may not work because the array that we are getting is 2-D .So we need to calculate the sum of array values.

```
$sum = array_sum(array_values($num));
```

Comment: you'll get syntax error with this code, use $ for variable name

Comment: Thanks..Sorry i missed it